# Update view on TabController swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've a tabbed app, I've a "Profile tab" that let me check my profile info ONLY if logged in.

If I'm not logged in, I call a method that show a new page that ask me if I want login (this page have a button that unwind to the first tab [that is not profile tab]).

I would that if i close this page with the button (so i'm going to the first tab), when i re-tap on the "Profile tab" it recall the method that open the login page.

I hope you understand the problem...

Thank you!!

PS. if it could help: I need a procedure that let me to call a method every time I open that tab

EDIT: CODE

```
func newMethod(){
    print("login: \(login)")

    let userFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserEntity")

    do{
        let users = try moc.fetch(userFetch)
        if(users.count > 0){
            print("utente connesso")
            login = 1
        }else{
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "area_utente_segue", sender: self)
            print("dovrebbe andare di la ")
        }
    }catch {}
}
```

this is the method called in viewWillAppear. With the help of @Sotiris Kaniras now every time i press on the tab, the method works. The problem is that it doesn't perform segue "area_utente_segue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you can override the viewWillAppear: method... That way, whenever your viewController is about to appear, it will automatically call viewWillAppear... Just like viewDidLoad...

Comment: i've tried..  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        newMethod()
    } but it doesn't work

Comment: I've edited my first post and added a comment. viewWillAppear works. But performSegue doesn't work